# Electron.js cannot save pdf files via jspdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, electron, jspdf

My goal is to save some parts of the view from current window as a PDF file, using canvas first. I used a solutions proposed in [this](https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e) tutorial.

```
$('#to_pdf').on('click', function(){
    const filename = "myfile.pdf"
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#myElement'))
    .then(canvas => {
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p', mm', 'a4')
      pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0,0,211,298)
      pdf.save(filename)
    })
})
```

After clicking on button with 'to_pdf' id html2canvas should transform part of my view into canvas and then save it as pdf to the user's directory. Im inside this function, everything is executed without any errors. However *pdf.save(filename)* is not working since I cannot save pdf.

Is this an electron restriction which prevent me from saving files by default? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This Code is working fine(single quote is missing)

after i add single quote

```
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', mm', 'a4')<----------jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')
```

working code in my electron app

```
$('#to_pdf').on('click', function(){
    const filename = "myfile.pdf"
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#myElement'))
    .then(canvas => {
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')
      pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0,0,211,298)
      pdf.save(filename)
    })
})
```